# MVC Updating individual row of table data POST

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm displaying only a few rows of data, each row will have the same input fields and an 'Update' submit button.

I'm a little stuck on how I would go about updating each individual row of data via POST?

So far i've got a view

```
@model IEnumerable <PGS.Areas.Case.Models.SurveyorsOfferModel>
<table>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                using (Html.BeginForm("EditSurveyor", "ValuationsAndOffers", new { id = @item.Id }, FormMethod.Post))
                {
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Surveyor</th>
                            <th>Date</th>
                            <th>M.V.</th>
                            <th>4-6 Week</th>
                            <th>Valuation to Use</th>
                            <th>Use</th>
                            <th>Report Received</th>
                            <th width="70"></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.HiddenFor(model => item.Id)
                                @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.SupplierName)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => item.ValuationDateTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control datepicker" } })
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => item.Valuation1, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control currency_input" } })
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => item.Valuation2, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control currency_input" } })
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DropDownList("ValuationToUse", item.ValuationToUseList, new { @class = "form-control small" })
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => item.UseInOffer, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control chk" } })
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => item.ReportReceivedDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control datepicker" } })
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input id="btnSubmit_@item.Id" type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-info" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>

                </table>
                }
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

I've put each "Row" within it's own table so I can wrap each in a form, but when I submit a row the model values are always null.

So not sure if there is something else I need to do to get the submitted data for the particular row?

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditSurveyor(SurveyorsOfferModel model)
{
    try
    {
        SurveyorsOffer c = efContext.SurveyorsOffers.Where(x => x.Id == model.Id).Single<SurveyorsOffer>();
        c.ValuationDateTime = model.ValuationDateTime;
        c.Valuation1 = model.Valuation1;
        c.Valuation2 = model.Valuation2;
        c.ValuationUsed = model.ValuationUsed;
        c.UseInOffer = model.UseInOffer;
        c.ReportRecievedDate = model.ReportReceivedDate;

        efContext.SubmitChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "ValuationsAndOffers", new { id = model.CaseId });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, ex.Message);
    }

    return View("Index", "~/Views/Shared/_Case_Template.cshtml", model);

}
```

Model

```
public class SurveyorsOfferModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int CaseId { get; set; }
        public int SupplierId { get; set; }
        public string SupplierName { get; set; }
        public string SupplierDetails { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ValuationDateTime { get; set; }
        public decimal? Valuation1 { get; set; }
        public decimal? Valuation2 { get; set; }
        public string ValuationUsed { get; set; }
        public bool UseInOffer { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ReportReceivedDate { get; set; }
        public string ContactName { get; set; }
        public string ContactEmail { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateAdded { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ValuationToUseList { get; set; }
    }
```

Rendered Form HTML

```
<form action="/Case/ValuationsAndOffers/EditSurveyor/2654" method="post">
<table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Surveyor</th>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>M.V.</th>
                        <th>4-6 Week</th>
                        <th>Valuation to Use</th>
                        <th>Use</th>
                        <th>Report Received</th>
                        <th width="70"></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Id must be a number." data-val-required="The Id field is required." id="item_Id" name="item.Id" type="hidden" value="2654" />
                        Allen &amp; Harris
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input class="form-control datepicker text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field ValuationDateTime must be a date." id="item_ValuationDateTime" name="item.ValuationDateTime" type="datetime" value="" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input class="form-control currency_input text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Valuation1 must be a number." id="item_Valuation1" name="item.Valuation1" type="text" value="" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input class="form-control currency_input text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Valuation2 must be a number." id="item_Valuation2" name="item.Valuation2" type="text" value="" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select class="form-control small" id="ValuationToUse" name="ValuationToUse"><option value="MV">M.V.</option>
    <option value="4_6">4-6 Week</option>
    </select>

                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input class="form-control chk check-box" data-val="true" data-val-required="The UseInOffer field is required." id="item_UseInOffer" name="item.UseInOffer" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="item.UseInOffer" type="hidden" value="false" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input class="form-control datepicker text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field ReportReceivedDate must be a date." id="item_ReportReceivedDate" name="item.ReportReceivedDate" type="datetime" value="" />
                    </td>
                    <td>

                        <input id="btnSubmit_2654" type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-info" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>

            </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: Examine your rendered form. The input `name` values should match the model's property names for binding to work. Verify this in the network request with the browser's debugger as well.

Comment: Yes the values are in the form data, but when debugging the property values in the model are all null.

Comment: Show us the rendered form and the `SurveyorsOfferModel` definition.

Comment: I've added the `SurveyorsOfferModel` and rendered form. Would it make any difference all of the above is a partial view?

Comment: You can only submit one form at a time, so what is the point of generating one form for each item (you just generating a whole lot of extra html). Either generate form controls for each item in one for using a `for `loop and post back all changes at once, of have a modal form that is populated with the details of a selected item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that the model needs to be an individual item instead of the enumeration.

Parent View:

```
@model IEnumerable <PGS.Areas.Case.Models.SurveyorsOfferModel>
<table>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
               @Html.Partial("ChildView",item)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

ChildView:

```
@model PGS.Areas.Case.Models.SurveyorsOfferModel
using (Html.BeginForm("EditSurveyor", "ValuationsAndOffers", new { id = @Model.Id }, FormMethod.Post))
{
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Surveyor</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>M.V.</th>
                <th>4-6 Week</th>
                <th>Valuation to Use</th>
                <th>Use</th>
                <th>Report Received</th>
                <th width="70"></th>
           </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
           <tr>
                <td>
                   @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
                   @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SupplierName)
                </td>
                <td>
                   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ValuationDateTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control datepicker" } })
                </td>
                ... 
                <td>
                   <input id="btnSubmit_@Model.Id" type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-info" />
                </td>
           </tr>
        </tbody>

    </table>
}
```

Comment: I've also added an answer below that solved an issue I ran into after using this method.

Answer (score 1):

Binding matches the `name` attribute. This will bind to the model's `Id` property:

```
<input name="Id" value="1" type="text" />
```

Your view contains a collection which you iterate. Using the form helpers in this way generates name attributes that won't bind.

```
<input name="item.Id" value="" type="text" />
```

**Override Name Attribute**

The `EditorFor()` won't let you override the name attribute so use `TextBoxFor()` instead.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => item.Id, new { @Name="Id" })
```

*Note the capitalization of Name*

**Use model instead**

It would also work if you change the variable name from `item` to `model`.

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => model.Id)
```

Generates

```
<input name="Id" id="Id" type="text" />
```

But this feels magical and hacky to me. It also forces you to use "model" in your foreach loop.

Comment: model is the ienumerable, so the properties don't exist on it. A partial view is needed here.

Comment: The page model is `IEnumerable` but only one item is submitted. Each item generates a complete form. A child view is a nice way to avoid the problem but doesn't explain as clearly why the values are null.

Comment: My bad, missed that you renamed `item` to `model`. I'm surprised that works. Definitely hackish.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note to add in case anyone else is stuck on something similar.

BK2's answer was correct and helped me get it working, but I ran into issues (as I thought I might) with form elements having duplicate Id's, so I then had to set the Id and Name attributes for each form item, with the Id being unique.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReportReceivedDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "ReportReceivedDate" + @Model.SurveyorOfferId, @name = "ReportReceivedDate", @class = "form-control datepicker", @Value = string.Format("{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", @Model.ReportReceivedDate) } })
```

Comment: Just use `new { id = "" }` to remove the `id` attribute and NEVER set the `value` attribute and your `@name = "ReportReceivedDate"` does absolutely nothing. But its crazy to degrade your app by sending 4 times as much html to the view as necessary, not to mention which the user might edit multiple forms and click submit thinking that all the data they entered will be saved. And you will never be able to use client side validation.